# How do I fix a leak in my sink's drain pipe?

Tags: water, leak, pvc

Started facing a water leak issue on pvc pipe under the bathroom sink. I am new to this and never fixed this before.
How do i fix this leak ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Find out exactly where leak is coming from.  For a drain pipe, it seems like the pipe and sink should be full of water(blocked) for that much of a leak.

Comment: Finding the source of a leak isn't rocket science. Dry the area thoroughly and run some water. Stop back when you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the source of the leak is up high. You could try simply tightening that threaded joint. If it's difficult to tighten then it could be cross-threaded.

If tightening it doesn't work then make sure your sink is not clogged, unscrew that joint, re-seat it, and screw it back together.

[image]

Additionally, if your sink is clogged and has standing water then unclogging it could make the problem go away.

Comment: I had a similar leak months ago. The plastic drain in the bottom of the sink bowl was cracked. The crack was completely invisible until I disassembled the drain.

Comment: @longneck, that belongs in an answer or in a comment on the question. It's not relevant to this answer.